# Ruby one liner lazy string evaluation

Tags: ruby

I'd like to create ruby one liner that prints some information to stdout and gets data from stdin. I've got some code:

```
["This should be shown first", "This second: #{gets.chomp}"].each{|i| puts "#{i}"}
```

...but apparently, get.chomp is evaluated in the same time when whole array is evaluated, before iteration of each element.

In result, I'm first prompted for input, and then each element is printed.

Can I somehow evaluate it lazily, print array in order and still have whole thing in one line?

Comment: More generally, whenever you want delayed execution, think "proc".

Comment: ...or "method". :-) (See below.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve lazy evaluation is to use procs. Something like this (multiple lines for *readability*):

```
[
  -> { puts "This should be shown first" }, 
  -> { print "This second: "; puts gets.chomp },
].each(&:call)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see the advantage of making this a one-liner since it becomes pretty unreadable, but nevertheless:

```
[ ->{ "This should be shown first" },
  ->{ "This second: #{gets.chomp}" }
].each {|line| puts line.call }
```

P.S. Never do `"#{foo}"`. Use string interpolation (`#{...}`) when you want to, well, interpolate strings, as on the second line above. If you want to turn a non-string into a string, do `foo.to_s`. If you know it's already a string (or don't care if it is) just use it directly: `foo`. But `puts` automatically calls `to_s` on its arguments, so just do `puts foo`.

Comment: This will ask for the input _before_ printing the second line. Not sure if this is desired behaviour or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind the repetiton of puts:

```
['puts "This should be shown first"', 'puts "This second: #{gets.chomp}"'].each{|i| eval i}
```

Comment: Just cross your fingers and hope your user doesn't enter ``"; `rm -rf /` ``

Comment: I agree, eval should be used with care. In this case I think its fine. First: The user running this probably has shell access already (OP not clear on the context). Second: The injection does not work like that. My guess is, that the string interpolation inhibits the evaluation, by escaping the '"'

Comment: @dabai: why don't you try this on your machine? :)

Comment: I did try it with '"; ´rm foo´'

Answer (score 0):

This is just to show you could use a method rather than a proc.

```
def line2
  "#{["cat","dog"].sample}"
end  

["Line 1", :line2, "line 3"].each { |l| puts (l.is_a? Symbol) ? method(l).call : l }
  #=> dog
```